# IDXGIFactory1::isCurrent(), when does it return TRUE?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, directx-11, dxgi

I'm using `IDXGIFactory1::isCurrent()` to detect when display topology has changed.

The documentation says;

> FALSE, if a new adapter is becoming available or the current adapter
>   is going away. TRUE, no adapter changes. IsCurrent returns FALSE to
>   inform the calling application to re-enumerate adapters.

However it seems to return TRUE after an WM_DISPLAYCHANGE message, for example after entering fullscreen mode.

Am I really expected to re-enumerate all DXGI topology after going fullscreen? Does anybody know how this works?

Comment: It's been a while since I dug into things at this level, but I don't think going fullscreen constitutes the removal of an adapter.  An adapter would be added or removed when a display is dynamically attached/removed to the computer (i.e. you just connected a 2nd monitor).

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, but IDXGIFactory1::isCurrent() returns TRUE before setting a swapchain fullscreen, and FALSE afterwards.